# working with bitbucket and native android development

Tags: android, eclipse, git, sdk, bitbucket

I am new to Android development Platform. Here is what I am currently facing

I am trying to create this app in Eclipse with two more people working on same app. I am using bitbucket over git plugin to share that project with other two. In this app I have used facebook sdk to enable users of app to log in using their facebook login details till everything is fine on my local machine I can run this app and its working perfectly. Now when I commit this code and push it to bitbucket repo other members are not able to see either facebook sdk folder when they pull from bitbucket repo. 
My questions

1. When i have downloaded facebook sdk from git do i need to move it into C:\Users\myname\git\mysampleapp\ or it doesn't matter where i keep it.
2. I also plan to use Gplus login my app for that i have to use Gplus sdk do i need to do same process as Facebook sdk?